# How to generate a string of random symbols from a string using python's random module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok, so i want the python's random module to choose 10 random symbols from a string and print it into the console. random.choices returns a list but i want a string like "1jF7Ud7oVj". How can i do this?

Comment: pick random integers and index them into the string

Answer (score 2):

You can just wrap the list with `''.join()`, for example:

```py
>>> ''.join(random.choices('abcdef', k=10))
'befabfadee'
```

Answer (score 1):

choice works exactly like choices without returning as a list

```py
from random import choice
string="The day the earth stood still"
randoms=""
for i in range(10):
        randoms+=choice(string)
print(randoms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the string and random modules, this will not start from a seed value :

```
import string 
import random 
st = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k = 10)) 
print("The generated random string :",str(st))
```

You can use :

```
st = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k = 10))
```

for upper case strings and remove `+ string.digits` if no digits are required

Answer (score 0):

You can use `''.join(list_name)` to conjoin items in a list together